# Python - ImportError

Tags: python, importerror, lts

I have a module I have installed called `lts_fits`, and this is its path:

```
~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lts_fits
```

So it is clearly in the site packages folder. Within this folder, there is a python script:

```
lts_linefit.py
```

Yet when I have this line of code in my script:

```
from lts_fits import lts_linefit
```

I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named lts_fits

How? It's clearly in there, and I have tried this same syntax with other random scripts and they import just fine. For instance, a file `abc.py` located in the folder `~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy` imports just fine when I have the line `from sympy import abc`. What could be going wrong?

Comment: If you have the enthought distribution, How certain are you that when you get the `ImportError` that you're using the Enthought Python config?

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in `lts_fits`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `__init__.py` file in that directory (you do not have to put anything into the file, all you need to do is create it).

The easiest way to create said file is by using:

```
touch __init__.py
```

from within your `lts_fits` directory in your command line/terminal/console.

See this SO article: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

And the [Python Documentation for packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).